# Inserting multiple records into database php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working with php Shopping cart.
I would like to insert records from one page to another page.
Such as after I click on buy button for my products page,
the products that I've bought will be listed in my shopping cart(which I've done it).
When I select "check out",it will insert the whole list of products in my cart.
However, I couldn't do so.
When I select "check out", it only manage to insert ONE products/records, instead of the whole list of products/records.
May I know how can I do it, to insert the whole list of records into database?

Below is my code for insert,I am not using SESSION to store ; and also, I know about the SQL injection, but I'm trying to do the basic first, so wouldn't be touching on SQL injection.
Can someone help me with it?
Your help will be truly appreciated!(:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "checkout_form")) {

  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO transaction (username, items, packaging, qty, price, imagename, `date`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['username'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['items'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['package'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['qty'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['price'], "double"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['imagename'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['date'], "date"));

        mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyDatabase);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
  $insertGoTo = "transaction.php";

  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }

  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to store all your products in your cart to the database at the end of the checkout process, but you don't use a session as a temporary persistence storage. You must store your cart somewhere (Cookie/Session) in order to have your whole cart at the end of the checkout process, so you could do something like this:

(Note this is pseudo code, and far away from good oop style, just so that you get the idea)

```
// Use-Case: Customer adds a product into his cart
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
$cart['positions'][] = array('item' => $_POST['item'], /* all your position information here */

// Use-Case: Customer wants to end the checkout process
foreach ($card['positions'] as $position) {
    // Your datbase insert for a position here
}
```

Comment: can I don't use session?
because,
when I select "buy", the products will be in my shopping cart and  is store in my database(cart),
when I select "checkout", the products in shopping cart and database(cart) will be inserted into database(trancart)

Comment: So, you have 2 databases for a cart and you want to copy from the first database to the second?

Comment: when I select "buy", it will go to shopping cart, I store the items that I buy in the database(cart).

when I select "checkout", it will insert the records from database(cart) , to database(trancart).
right now, I'm only able to insert ONE records at a time.
Just wondering, how can I insert the whole lot of products that I've bought into the database